# What's the best way to use wildcard expansion in bash when source and destination are similar?

Tags: bash, wildcards, mv

Suppose I have these folders:

```
$ ls
css-tricks/ django-tutorial/ good-tuts.txt js-tut/ tutorials/ tuts.txt
```

Some of these have `tut` in their names. I would like to move all the files/folders that have `tut` in their names into the folder `tutorials/`. If I execute the command

```
$ mv *tut* tutorials/
```

I get the following message:

`mv: cannot move 'tutorials' to a subdirectory of itself, 'tutorials/tutorials'`

What can I do to avoid such a scenario?

---

One of the tricks that I am able to think of is to rename the destination folder to something else temporarily, and after the command executes, change it back to the desired name. However, I'm hoping to know a more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Why _what_ workds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, in a situation where I'm about to give the command interactively, I would just do `mv *tut* tutorials` and expect to get the "cannot move" error.  It's is harmless and the other files and directories will have been moved as expected.

The exit status of the command will be non-zero, signalling an error, but since nothing depends on it, it may be ignored.

---

In this case, the other names contains a dash before `tut`:

```
mv *-tut* tutorials
```

Or, if you also have things like `python_tut` that you want to move, also allow for an underscore:

```
mv *[_-]tut* tutorials
```

Or, to require any extra character before the substring `tut` (which `tutorials` does not have),

```
mv *?tut* tutorials
```

With a bit more typing and thinking, using an extended globbing pattern in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv *tut!(orials*) tutorials
```

This second variation will match anything that contains the substring `tut` not immediately followed by the string `orials`.  The pattern would not match `tutorials` and would also skip `tutorials1` etc.

Comment: What if I have names like, `python_tut`? I also don't want to pay too much attention to the exact names. I just want to know that I some files have `tut` in their names, regardless of what character comes before, or after, and it should just work.

Comment: @RifazNahiyan See the addition to the answer.

Comment: Yep. That works too. But I'm still looking for something simpler... I feel like I have some knowledge gap regarding bash-expansions, and the more elegant solution lies within that gap.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `find`:

```
find . -type d -name "*tut*" -not -path "./tutorials" -exec mv -t "tutorials" {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get the following message:
>
> ```
> mv: cannot move 'tutorials' to a subdirectory of itself, 'tutorials/tutorials'
> ```

Just ignore the error.

No, really. You know you're going to get the error since the glob pattern matches the target. You also know it doesn't mean anything, since the system can't move the directory inside itself, and it's smart to enough to realize it before messing up your filesystem.

Comment: If I now do, `cp -r *tut* tutorials/`, I get the message `cp: cannot copy a directory, 'tutorials', into itself, 'tutorials/tutorials'` and find that this directory gets created: `tutorials/tutorials`, albeit is empty. Also, I have the fear that ignoring that message might yield me to scarier situations involving recursion one day.

Comment: @RifazNahiyan, well, you did write `mv` and not `cp` in the question. Honestly, I have never thought of it with `cp`, but with `mv` I just ignore the error. With `mv` the OS has to block it, since otherwise the directory hierarchy would get busted. With `cp` it's not that straightforward. But yeah, (current-ish) GNU `cp` also seems to know to stop after just creating the empty directory. On the other hand, the ancient one on my Mac happily recursed until the path names got too long.

Answer (score 0):

you have following file in you directory

```
css-tricks/ django-tutorial/ good-tuts.txt js-tut/ tutorials/
```

the command

```
mv *tut*
```

will be expended by bash as

```
mv django-tutorial/ good-tuts.txt js-tut/ tutorials/
```

- if last argument of `mv` is a directory, `mv` will move all argument to that directory.
- since last argument is the directory you want to move file into, this will do.

You can preview the change using

```
echo mv *tut*
```

and see if proper directory is last in command line.

---

Note that

```
mv *tut* tutorials/
```

is expended as

```
mv django-tutorial/ good-tuts.txt js-tut/ tutorials/ tutorials/
```

which give the error you've seen.

Note also, should you have a `tutorails.old/` directory, the trick will not work.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. That's fantastic!

Comment: But, how will bash know that I want the folders to move into `tutorials` and not the others?

Comment: yes, only use this trick if you know what you are doing. (I added a "preview" option)

Comment: This only works since `tutorials` happens to be the last one in sort order in this particular case. Counting on that is really fishy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to rename the target directory `tutorials/` to something else that isn't matched in the filename expansion, and rename it to your desire after performing the move.